# I need paper about trinomial over finite field Irreducible 3 rd order

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

I am PhD student in trinomial over finite field

I need paper or information or PDF about trinomial over finite field in the following form for example

$$
f(x)=x^{2\times3^k}+x^k+1
$$
If any one know the family of this trinomial.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you address such a question to https://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: Not sure this is MO level, but admittedly somebody there may know a reference. Exactly what you are a PhD student on? Trinomials over finite fields are an awfully narrow area of specialization. Anyway, a lot will depend on the characteristic of the field.

Comment: And exactly what do you want to know about these trinomials?

Comment: Reposted at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/287502/15503).